# Java web development servlet changes not executed

Tags: jsp, servlets, web, web.xml

I'm developing a java web development project in eclipse.
In my project under src i have a package called com.ptm
In this package i have a servlet called LoginServlet.java which has been working fine. When called from my jsp page it would check the call other classes to check login, if invalid it would redirect to "Login.jsp"
This was all working fine, but I thought i would rename the Login.jsp to login.jsp
I changed all my references in other jsp's and in the servlet, but now when i run my project and the invalid statement is called, it still tried to open 'Login.jsp' instead of 'login.jsp' 
I have restarted tomcat and restarted eclipse multiple times. I have also entered a print statement in this loop and ran it through the debugger, what i see is it completely missing out my print statement. It looks as though its stepping through but the code its actually stepping through is different.
I have also corrupted the LoginServlet with random text so it should load an error but it still runs fine.

I have referenced the servlet in WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ptm.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

And as i say it used to run fine, but it seems as through the servlet is cached somewhere and i cant update it

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse there is an option under Project -> Clean. 
Select your web project and click Ok.

Clean feature will discard all build problems and build states. The project will be rebuilt from scratch.

Stop the Tomcat Server first. After cleaning project right click the project folder in project explorer and click on refresh(F5). Run the project now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems to have helped, no however when i run i'm getting NoClassDefFoundError and my javax.servlet imports don't seem to be resolving

Comment: ok, got it, had to reinport external jar "servlet-api" from tomcat directory. Now working Thanks loads!